# How can I stream video from my XP sp3 desktop to my win 7 laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, video, streaming

I would like to stream media from my XP sp3 desktop to my Win7 laptop.  I currently have Windows Media Player 11 on both machines.  The XP one is set up for the media sharing service as far as I can tell.  I have also set the 'Play To' option to my Win 7 machine on the XP WMP.

However, the only way I've been able to 'stream' is to simply tell my Win7 WMP to add a network folder to its libraries.  This seems to work over the wifi but it does stutter a touch, even with a 20 second buffer.  The stuttering also appears randomly, maybe 4-5 times during a 22 minute show.

I feel like I'm doing something wrong.  Is this setup OK or am I missing something?

Comment: Any compelling reason you don't just temporarily copy the files to your laptop?

Comment: No not really, just wanted to try out streaming and avoid that extra step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try VLC:

- http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html